# One question about Multiple Inheritance Method Resolution Order in Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Here is my python 3 codes in the Jupyter notebook:

```
class X: pass
class Y: pass
class Z: pass
class A(X,Y): pass
class B(Y,Z): pass
```

When I tried:

```
class M(A,B,Z): pass
print(M.mro())
```

The output shows:

```
[<class '__main__.M'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.Y'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <class 'object'>]
```

When I switched the position of A and B:

```
class M(B,A,Z): pass
print(M.mro())
```

The output shows:

```
[<class '__main__.M'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.Y'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Why is the method resolution order different? Does the position of A and B matter? Is there something that I'm missing? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Take a look at [this description](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)